# Create a channel system using FFMPEG and FFserver

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, ffserver

I have been looking all over the internet but cannot find the answer, am I able to create a channeling system with `FFMPEG` and `ffserver`? what I want to do is give users the ability to dynamically add their `ip address` and start restreaming their cameras (from a predefined list). Would I have to open different instances or can I dynamically add feeds to ffserver, or is this not a viable option?

Any help is appreciated, 
Thank you.